# Add a Double tap listener to a View in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, listener

I am trying to add a double tap listener on a `TextView`. I know I might have to use `GestureDetector`, but I am not exactly sure how you do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// Instantiate the gesture detector with the
        // application context and an implementation of
        // GestureDetector.OnGestureListener
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        // Set the gesture detector as the double tap
        // listener.
        mDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);
```

or use the given link.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Detecting_Common_Gestures_using_the_Android_Gesture_Detector_Class

Comment: That adds a Gesture Detector on the Activity. I am trying to add it specifically on a TextView